# Converting a polygon to an area returns an empty area

Tags: java

Throughout my application I have extensively used `java.awt` and `java.awt.geom` to detect collisions etc. But suddenly I've come across a problem that I cannot understand. When I try to convert a Polygon to an Area, the area returned is empty. Here's a snippet that shows the behaviour:

```
System.out.println("Room: " + this.roomGeometry.getBounds2D().getMinX() + ", " + this.roomGeometry.getBounds2D().getMaxX() + ", " + this.roomGeometry.getBounds2D().getMinY() + ", " + this.roomGeometry.getBounds2D().getMaxY());

Area t1 = new Area(this.roomGeometry);
System.out.println("Room: " + t1.getBounds2D().getMinX() + ", " + t1.getBounds2D().getMaxX() + ", " + t1.getBounds2D().getMinY() + ", " + t1.getBounds2D().getMaxY());
```

The output of this snippet is:

```
Room: -20.0, 20.0, 0.0, 50.0
Room: 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0
```

Can someone explain why that is?

---

Edit: the polygon is set in an XML parsing function using the following code:

```
int b_xvals[] = getIntArrayFromString(b.getElementsByTagName("xvals").item(0).getTextContent());
int b_yvals[] = getIntArrayFromString(b.getElementsByTagName("yvals").item(0).getTextContent());
game.setRoomGeometry(new Polygon(b_xvals,b_yvals,b_xvals.length));
```

I have checked, and the arrays contain the correct values.

Comment: Could you show us the polygon you are using? Does this happen with all polygons, or just some specific ones?

Comment: Could you include an example-geometry (coordinates for which this happens? Could not reproduce so far, even with sef-intersecting polygons

Comment: Right now the polygon representing the geometry of the room is a rectangle with xvals -20,20, and yvals 0,50. For some reason when I try converting that polygon to an area, the area has bounds 0,0,0,0.

Comment: You need 4 points for a rectangle represented as a Polygon.

Comment: Oh, silly me. I will correct that and see if it solves the issue.

Comment: Yep, that solved it.